# Cant install Ubuntu from USB

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

Here I am with freshly made Ubuntu USB installer ready to boot.
I need to boot it because this [Ubuntu does not boot, start - could not write bytes broken pipe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457865/ubuntu-does-not-boot-start-could-not-write-bytes-broken-pipe)
made me kill my hamster.

Anyway since I have given up on fixing my PC, I have decided to reinstall completely ubuntu.
I put inside my USB
Press <kbd>F12</kbd> during startup to enter bios - there I press boot from USB
Another Ubuntu screen with a small stick figure pops up and usb next to it, I HAVE to press <kbd>enter</kbd> otherwise it leads to the restart and again Broken Pipe thing, it follows up with choosing language pops up, so I choose it and

Then these options of installation

Try Ubuntu without installation
Check Memory
Install Ubuntu
Check disk
Start of system from first disk (this just repeats the whole process since usb is there as first and Only)

Rest of the choices lead to restart of the PC and...again 
Broken Pipe, could not write bytes - screen.

So....how do I get rid of it?

Comment: What computer brand, model, and specification are you using? What OS previously functioned on this computer? What flavor/release of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Also, be careful on the double-posting...moderators will kill one if they feel it is a violation.

Comment: Lenovo b590, no OS other than Ubuntu 12.4 and i want to use it again, however something messed up during installation of some...packs, which I killed the process in progress, after restart it didnt boot

Comment: I believe something happened during manual installation of the packs through the terminal - that process I killed.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong here - please try and recreate another USB installer - see official article about [installing ubuntu from USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) as a guide. To make sure use the other option of try ubuntu without installing to see if boots. If it does not boot then I would definately recreate the USB stick. Lastly make sure you are using a larger capacity memory stick for the bootable disk - I would recommend anything from 4GB upwards just to be sure. Good luck

Comment: Make sure you are using an appropriate method to create the USB installer, as the install guide indicates. Also a good idea to run the test media option from the initial menu.

Comment: problem is that, that the USB works fine on my friends laptop when I want to use it as installer.
32GB
Try ubuntu without installing - did not boot just restarted

Comment: It seems it could be something to do with NVIDIA - see this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2058521 maybe the user aplonis and other answers could help you.